# macbook 10.15.5 install maven failed: NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Tags: macos, maven

I know there are a lot of questions/answers about this question, but all were failed in my case.
I installed jdk 1.8 and then installed maven3.6.3, java runs well but mvn command didn't work, see my command output and env:

java -version

```sh
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

mvn -v

```sh
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

mac OS version: 10.15.5
[image]

echo $JAVA_HOME

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
```

echo $PATH

```
/usr/local/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:.
```

config in ~/.bash_profile

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.6.3
PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:.
#Mac OSX 10.15.5 or later version need this configure
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:.
export PATH
```

I also source ~./bash_profile to make configure effective.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest revert all the changes you have made in `~/.bash_profile`. Checkout my way to make the maven work:

1. Download latest maven zip package `apache-maven-<version>-bin.zip` from Apache maven download page.
2. Unzip it to any place, e.g: ~/Develop/apache-maven-3.6.0
3. Create a link with command `sudo ln -sf ~/Develop/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/mvn /usr/local/bin/mvn` (change version number per your case, if the local bin folder missing, just create it `mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`).
4. Check the installation `mvn --version`

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i try another way and it works, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After hundreds updating configure file, now `mvn -version` can works, share my update and hope it can help you.

fill or update `vim ~/.mavenrc`(in the beginning, this file isn't exist)

```sh
# my MacOS is 10.15+
export Java_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/Java_home)
```

and then `source ~/.mavenrc` to let system env effective.

Summary：for my mac system, seems maven couldn't get `JAVA_HOME` from `.bash_profile` or `.profile`, so if you confirm your JAVA_HOME is set correctly and MAVEN_HOME configured, then you can have a try in this way.

Comment: Note: i installed MySQL and found that in `.bash_profile`, you need to ensure export all your HOME(MYSQL_HOME, JAVA_HOME etc.) before PATH, else mysql command won't work.